# Python soap requests (VIES)

Tags: python, soap, python-requests

I'm trying to send soap request to check if clients NIP is valid via Python

```
import requests
url="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatTestService.wsdl"

headers = {"content-type" : "application/soap+xml"}
body = """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:checkVat>
         <urn:countryCode>SK</urn:countryCode>
         <urn:vatNumber>2020016449</urn:vatNumber>
      </urn:checkVat>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

response = requests.post(url, data = body, headers = headers)
print(response)
```

I always get code 200 which means it's invalid, but their webpage says it is valid.
I've seen other methods, but I really need to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will produce the following result:

```
<Response [200]>
```

which is correct, but it's not what you expect, because I believe there are a few misunderstandings at play here.

First of all, `<Response [200]>` is the response of the HTTP request, not the response of the web service. Don't confuse the two. You are making a SOAP call over HTTP. That HTTP response will have a HTTP response code, which in this case is 200, and a SOAP payload with the response of the web service inside, and that's what's you are mostly interested in.

Second, you are not calling the web service endpoint. You are making a request to the WSDL of the web service. [The two are different](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b). You could have noticed that by replacing the last line of code with `print(response.text)` and you would have seen the WSDL content there.

The endpoint of the service is found inside the WSDL and it is `http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService`. This is where you have to POST the request.

Third, based on the documentation in the WSDL, this seems a test service that gives you back all the possible responses of the service depending on which VAT number you use:

```
<xsd:documentation>
 Specific disclaimer for this service ----------------------------------------- 
 Here is the list of VAT Number to use to receive each kind of answer : 
    100 = Valid request with Valid VAT Number
    200 = Valid request with an Invalid VAT Number
    201 = Error : INVALID_INPUT
    202 = Error : INVALID_REQUESTER_INFO
    300 = Error : SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
    301 = Error : MS_UNAVAILABLE
    302 = Error : TIMEOUT
    400 = Error : VAT_BLOCKED
    401 = Error : IP_BLOCKED
    500 = Error : GLOBAL_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ
    501 = Error : GLOBAL_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ_TIME
    600 = Error : MS_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ
    601 = Error : MS_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ_TIME
    
    For all the other cases, The web service will responds with a "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" error.
</xsd:documentation>
```

Use this code instead:

```
import requests
url="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService"

headers = {"content-type" : "application/soap+xml"}
body = """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:checkVat>
         <urn:countryCode>SK</urn:countryCode>
         <urn:vatNumber>2020016449</urn:vatNumber>
      </urn:checkVat>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

response = requests.post(url, data = body, headers = headers)
print(response.text)
```

When you call it you will get (formatting not included):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

which is exactly what I expect because the documentation says it: *For all the other cases, The web service will responds with a "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" error.*

If I want a a valid response I only need to change the VAT number to this within the SOAP request message: `<urn:vatNumber>100</urn:vatNumber>` and now the service responds with (formatting not included):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <checkVatResponse xmlns="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
    <countryCode>SK</countryCode>
    <vatNumber>100</vatNumber>
    <requestDate>2022-03-27+02:00</requestDate>
    <valid>true</valid>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <address>123 Main St, Anytown, UK</address>
  </checkVatResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```